# Mapping URLs with different port in Apache

Tags: virtualhost, http

I have a URL:

```
http://ip:9200/_plugin/head/
```

I want to open that URL when I visit:

```
http://ip/es-head
```

How do I do that in Apache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`mod_proxy`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html). Apache configuration would look like this:

```
ProxyPass /es-head/ http://ip:9200/_plugin/head/
ProxyPassReverse /es-head/ http://ip:9200/_plugin/head/
```

[Apache manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html) has some examples.